# Как сделать автоматическую замену значения input?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть инпут. Нужно чтобы , когда пользователь вводит число например 2,3445 оно автоматически заменялось на 2.34 .

```js
var inp = $('.num');
$('.num').keyup(function () {
      
    if (!this.value.match(/^[0-9,.]+$/)) {
        this.value = this.value.replace(/[^0-9,.]/g, '');
    }
       
     var val = $('.num').val();
     //console.log(val);
     var numReplace = val.replace(",", ".");
     var numToFloat = parseFloat(numReplace);
     var num = numToFloat.toFixed(2);
     inp.val(num);
   
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" class='num' > </input>
```

В консоли все работает, но вот в реальном инпуте нет. Число то заменяется, но потом курсор встает в конец строки и очень сложно тогда его отредактировать. Как сделать чтобы после автокорекции числа его можно было без проблем снова изменять?

Comment: Встречный вопрос: а как программа должна понимать, что пользователь закончил ввод числа?

Comment: не знаю . поэтому и обратился сюда

Comment: а может просто повесить на input change? Получится что когда пользователь закончил ввод, все и округляется и запятая заменяется... И пользователь обращать внимание не будет и вам проще и не нужно 100 раз проверять корректность ввода...

Answer (score 0):

Проблема Вашего кода в том, что неизвестно когда пользователь заканчивает ввод. С большой долей вероятности можно предположить, что когда он покидает input, то он ввел именно то, что хотел.

Поэтому можно заменить `keyup` на `blur`. После этого, если понадобится, можно вернуться и отредактировать значение без проблем.

```js
var inp = $('.num');
$('.num').blur(function () {
      
    if (!this.value.match(/^[0-9,.]+$/)) {
        this.value = this.value.replace(/[^0-9,.]/g, '');
    }
       
     var val = $('.num').val();
     //console.log(val);
     var numReplace = val.replace(",", ".");
     var numToFloat = parseFloat(numReplace);
     var num = numToFloat.toFixed(2);
     inp.val(num);
   
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" class='num' > </input>
```